# asp.net site hosting in client ftp windows server Assembly missing error

Tags: asp.net, website-hosting

this my error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FlickrNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 12: using System.Xml.Linq;
Line 13:

**Line 14: using FlickrNet;**

Line 15: using System.Globalization;

Line 16:

Source File: e:\inetpub\vhosts\thecouncilhost.com\httpdocs\kidzania\Flickr_Photo.aspx.cs    Line: 14

e:\inetpub\vhosts\thecouncilhost.com\httpdocs\kidzania\Flickr_Photo.aspx.cs(14,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FlickrNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

e:\inetpub\vhosts\thecouncilhost.com\httpdocs\kidzania\Flickr_Photo.aspx.cs

this not my computer path that one is Client windows server path

another one file upload after Publish web through Dot net below the error

Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Kidzania_Final.login, App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this stack trace error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FlickrNet' could not be found 
(are you missing  a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Have you `FlickrNet` dll in your `bin` or `App_Code` directory of your solution???
If not, then add that library dll in project and remember to check `copy local` check box while adding reference in your project.

Comment: i add that dll file in my bin already, this website project work local system, actually this error occurs upload to remote ftp server

Comment: recompile and publish your website again .. it may solve your problem.

Comment: sorry more and more time repeat that step but it not worked. :( and finally i not sure about publish.

Comment: can u help me what is the way for publish, or any suggest website are u know

Comment: refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for publishing website after compilation and then configure IIS virtual directory to show your publish.

Comment: that same method for hosting my website in WWW or any modified methods

Comment: well.. try this.. hope this help.. consider answering and up voting  your question's answers that will somewhat fit your solution.., it will encourage others to help you..

Comment: thanks for your time and suggestion, the links which you gave was useful but i need detail about "key container" thanks in advance